# After installing RHEL in Parallels on my Mac how do I log in?

Tags: macos, parallels, rhel6

I installed RHEL 6.4 server under Parallels 7 on my Mac OS 10.8 just now from an iso file I just downloaded from RedHat. The installation seemed to proceed ok, but at the end I'm left with a screen with a gray bar followed by the text "RedHat Enterprise Linux Server 6.4" with no obvious way how to login.

If I shut down the machine I see it running the shutdown scripts. If I boot it I see the boot scripts and they all look ok. But I always end up at that same screen with no way to login.

I can enter characters in the screen, but there is no Linux prompt at all.

Anybody know what to do next? I couldn't glean anything fro the RedHat install manual.

Thanks,

doug

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  The issue is the X-win server will not start because Parallels tools breaks the framebuffer with the RHEL 6.4 update.  This is especially easy to see because a fresh install works fine until you install Parallels tools.

When you see the "select system to boot" message, hit the key that allows you to edit the boot arguments.  Add a "3" to the end to force the startup to runlevel 3 (which is a console login without the GUI).

After logging in, type the command "starts" and you will see that it fails.  Once you are able to fix this problem, the normal bootup into the GUI login will also work.

I had to downgrade the video driver subsystem back to 6.3 for it to start working, and you also have to add an exclusion to yum to prevent it from updating and removing the fix.  This will be necessary until Parallels releases an updated tools that addresses this issue.  There is a procedure I found in the CentOS forums for how to do this, sorry I don't have the link.